# How to change an existing Xamarin Android 8 app to Android 9?

Tags: android, xamarin

I need to know how to change an existing Android 8 app to target Android 9.

How can I change the target Android API level?

Comment: What do you mean when you say migrate?

Comment: @FreakyAli I have updated the question.

Comment: So you have an issue while changing the `TargetAPI`?

Comment: What are the steps that you have done?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes. I have found the answer. See the answers below.

Comment: @Dustin I did not make any changes earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the Target Android Version field in the Android Manifest to target the Android 9. So the problem is solved.

[image]

Comment: Could you please mark your your solution as an answer  so that others who have silmilar question will get help from here?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang Done. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Happy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

you should probably also change the Compile version [image]

Comment: Hi this is xamarin with Visual Studio.